# Strange screens for a game

Tags: android, screen, screen-orientation

I am organising a hackathon at my company, to develop a game in Java. The competition I was asked to organise states that the game will be tested on "very unusual screens" and the assessor has "a variety of devices he may wish to use".

What kind of devices could this include?

I have already considered projectors or VR headsets, but are there common curved screens or non-rectangular? And what can be done to account for these and how should I grade submissions?

How much should I warn the participants about this?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/index.html and scroll down to "Build for a Multi-Screen World" You get some ideas.

Comment: I interesting Question but not a coding issue

Comment: Tell me where it should be and I will move it.